# How to add i18next translation to input's placeholder in React?

Tags: reactjs, translation, i18next, react-i18next

Ive translated whole app using `<Trans i18nKey="item.key">Fallback text</Trans>`

Only issue is that I can not do the same with inputs placeholder.

I tried with `<input placeholder={t('input.placeholder')}/>` and adding "t" to import `import { t, Trans } from "react-i18next";` but then I have error `Attempted import error: 't' is not exported from 'react-i18next'.`

Comment: I just read the first lines of getting started of this lib, it state that you will get the "t" variable by using the hooks "useTranslation" or the HOC "withTranslation". Please do your search

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [useTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook) hook?

---

You can just do

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { TFunction } from "i18next";
```

Then use it as below:

```
const { t }: {t: TFunction} = useTranslation()
```